# i can define a String.contain("-") to search for specific character "`-`" followed by one or more integers

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

i have a question if i can define a `String.contain("-")` to search for specific character "`-`" followed by one or more integers.

so it will cover something such as :-

```
search -12
t-123est
```

but will not cover

```
search-t12
t-est123
```

Comment: I don't think `String.Contains()` will help you in that case... Have you tried using `Regex`?

Comment: Yes, use regex.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a regular expression.

Comment: Here's the [docs for the Regex class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [good internet tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2):

You best option might not be to use `String.Contains`,  You might be best served using `Regex.IsMatch`.  With that you can define a regular expression that will exactly match your needs.  you can use sites like https://www.regex101.com/ to test your expression to make sure it covers your cases.  In your case, you can use

```
 Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"-\d+")
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be enough:

```
Regex.IsMatch("search -12", @"-\d")
```